# Room Float Type

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

I have the problem with migrating to Room from pure `SQLite`.

I have a `table` with `column` created as FLOAT and it's impossible to connect to this `table` from Room because it's required REAL.

Any ideas how to solve it?

I've found https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62875387, but there is no actual solution.

Comment: Create a migration that converts the column from `FLOAT` to `REAL`.

Comment: @CommonsWare how do we do that? I also have DATE, TIME that I am unable to migrate to room